# Object deconstruction use cases in C# 7.x

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

I've just been exploring the new things introduced in C# 7.x. I found the `Deconstructor` function pretty interesting.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FistName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public int Age { get; }

    public Person(string fistName, string lastName, int age)
    {
        Age = age;
        LastName = lastName;
        FistName = fistName;
    }

    public void Deconstruct(out string fistName, out string lastName, out int age) // todo 3.0 deconstructor function
    {
        fistName = FistName;
        lastName = LastName;
        age = Age;
    }
}

...

var person = new Person("John", "Smith", 18);
var (firstName, lastName, age) = person;

Console.WriteLine(firstName);
Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName); // not much difference really
```

The thing is, I cannot figure out a practical usage for it. "Object" deconstruction comes very handy in functional programming pattern matching. However I believe it cannot be used this way in C# (yet?). If not, are there any real world use cases?

Comment: The [language design meeting notes on Deconstructors](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/0709623617764880198f972d66845e88a89fe149/meetings/2016/LDM-2016-05-03-04.md) are probably relevant, but dont't provide very specific use cases. It seems like the overall case is that they wanted something extensible like GetEnumerator (for foreach) and GetAwaiter (async/await) rather than just special cases. This lets others implement tuple-like types is they so desire. It might not be generally useful for most users, but it is tremendously useful those who want to hook into the specific mechanism.

Comment: `I cannot figure out a practical usage for it.` you wrote one right there. More succinct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious use-case comes "built in", ie tuples:

```
(int x, int y) Foo() => (1, 2);

var (a, b) = Foo();
```

Rather than having to write:

```
var t = Foo();
var a = t.x;
var b = t.y;
```

My personal favourite use of deconstructs with tuples is for expression-bodied constructors that assign multiple fields:

```
class Bar
{
    private readonly int _a;
    private readonly int _b;
    private readonly int _c;

    public Bar(int a, int b, int c) => (_a, _b, _c) = (a, b, c);
}
```

I have used them in other scenarios (such as splitting a collection into its head and tail (cons, as it's called in F#), but deconstructing tuples remains the most common use case for me at least.